# Framework for Java distributed application health monitor?

Tags: java, distributed, rmi, jmx

I am working on a java distributed application that consists of a variety of RMI servers running on a collection of processors in an embedded system. The system reports status through a color-coded GUI which underneath periodically polls the RMI servers for their status (UP, DOWN, DEGRADED, etc.) using a defined Interface. Additionally, the servers report both SW and HW status.

I'm looking to replaced this custom tool with a more open framework. I know JMX can be used to do such a thing. I would need to setup a single MBeanServer that all the RMI servers would register with under unique ObjectNames. I'd also have to write a custom MBean that would supply the interface methods.

My question, is if anyone knows if there is already a framework built to do such a thing. Maybe also provide some type of control functionality (shutdown/restart service, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I recently attended a speech where they showed what you can do with RHQ (http://rhq-project.github.io/rhq/) and it was pretty impressive. Graphs, remote start/stop, alerting, history and zoom in/out but I didn't have time to play with it myself.